# shall we use $locationProvider in angular js ver 1.3.14

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use html5Mode for removing # from the url in SPAs. I got error while use $locationProvider in angularjs v 1.3.14.
I don't know why it's happening.i have mention below with code and my console error.

**Front End:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="sample-controller" class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Controller:**

```
var app=angular.module('app',['ngRoute','ngCookies']);

app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider','$httpProvider',function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider){
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : "/angular-practice/route/family.html",
        controller  : "sample-controller"
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl : "/angular-practice/route/login.html",
        controller  : "sample-controller"
    })
    .when('/oops', {
        templateUrl : "/angular-practice/route/oops.html",
        controller  : "sample-controller"
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/oops',controller  : "sample-controller" });

    //$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

    $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 5000;  
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);  
}]);
```

**Console Error**

```
Error: [$location:nobase] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$location/nobase
M/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:6:417
Me/this.$get<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:98:414
```

Answer (score 1):

You need ta add:

```
<base href="/">
```

in the head section of your main html file. This is because Angular requires you to specify the url base when setting "$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);". You can read about it in the documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location.

Your html file should look like this to work:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<base href="/">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">   </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="sample-controller" class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: im battling with this bro..thanks for your response.. i will try it

Comment: console error is "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/app/controller.js"..my html file path is angular-practice/route.and my index in root like inside angular-practice.and my controller inside app folder

Comment: i think it right way to my root <base href="/angular-practice/">

Comment: otherwise condition not working. like if any wrong path given, it doesn't redirect to oops page

Comment: I have tried your code and it works for me with "<base href="/">". You need to add a "#" for the routing to work. Try accessing for instance: localhost/#login, this should route you to the login page. localhost/#test should route you to the oops page because this route doesn't exist.